# Serializer NOT displaying object on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-serializer

I have created a test view to test the API, as follows:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from profiles_api import serializers


class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """Test API View"""

    serializers_class = serializers.HelloSerializer
    # specifies the Input expected when GET,PUT,POST,DELETE is requested

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """Returns a list of APIView features"""
        an_apiview = [
            "Uses HTTP methods as function (get, post, patch, put, delete)",
            "Similar to django view, but specific for APIs",
            "Gives you the most control over your application",
            "Is mapped manually to urls",
        ]

        return Response({"message": "Hello!", "an_apiview": an_apiview})

    def post(self, request):
        """Create a hello message with our name"""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        # serializers_class comes with the APIView that retrieves the configured Serializer Class for our view (Standard way)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.validated_data.get("name")
            message = f"Hello {name}"
            return Response({"message": message})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializers.py file looks like the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class HelloSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializes a name field for testing APIView"""

    # similar to django forms
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
```

When i run the server, the Django rest Framework does NOT show a form called name, but one called Content, and when i try to post a name for example "Hola", it throws an error (404 Bad request).

My urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from profiles_api import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("hello-view/", views.HelloApiView.as_view()),
]
```

I tried to solve it by adding a Meta Class in my serializers.py file, but it did not work:

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Kind Regards

Comment: Could you show us your `UserProfile` model, the `urls.py` file, and the error messages you are getting?

Comment: I tried to add a model to solve it, but the serializer does not depend on the model here.  I updated the question with my urls.py file

Comment: You are using `serializers.Serializer` it does not contain `model` in **Meta** class model is only for `ModelSerializer`

Comment: I think you've typo it should be `serializer_class` instead of `serializers_class`

Comment: Thanks Ankit, that was the problem, now solved :)